# Why my Glassfish throws exception pool-89-thread-1?

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish

sometimes my glassfish server shows the following errors in console, do you have any idea ?

```
SEVERE:     at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.signal(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1941)
SEVERE:     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1100)
SEVERE:     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:807)
SEVERE:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
SEVERE:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
SEVERE:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
SEVERE:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
SEVERE: Exception in thread "pool-89-thread-1" 
SEVERE: java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.signal(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1941)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1100)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:807)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With only the stacktrace provided we can see that this is clearly a multithreading type of exception. According to doc

> (IllegalMonitorStateException) Thrown to indicate that a thread has attempted to wait on an object's monitor or to notify other threads waiting on an object's monitor without owning the specified monitor.

See [Understanding Java Wait and Notify methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624503/understanding-java-wait-and-notify-methods) and the answer by Jon Skeet.

If you need more help try posting some code...